# add oneSignal plugin cordova - Ionic 2

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, ionic2, onesignal

I added onesignal-cordova-plugin to my project very well, but when I want to build (`ionic cordova run android`) I got this error :

```
Observed package id 'build-tools;26.0.0-rc1' in inconsistent location 'E:\SDK\build-tools\26.0.0-preview' (Expected 'E:\SDK\build-tools\26.0.0-rc1')
Errors during XML parse:
White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.]
Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0,26.1.0).
     Required by:
         project : > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.1
      > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0,26.1.0).
         > Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v4.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0,26.1.0).
         > Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v4.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml.
               > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:customtabs:[26.0.0,26.1.0).
     Required by:
         project : > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.1
      > Could not resolve com.android.support:customtabs:[26.0.0,26.1.0).
         > Failed to list versions for com.android.support:customtabs.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/customtabs/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/customtabs/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve com.android.support:customtabs:[26.0.0,26.1.0).
         >

BUILD FAILED
```

What is the problem? I saw a same error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837005/crosswalk-error-in-ionic-2)

**Maybe is related :**

The requested path was not found :

```
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
```

**Ionic Info**:

```
cli packages: 
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.9.2 
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2 

global packages: 
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 
Gulp CLI : CLI version 3.9.1 
Local version 3.9.1 

local packages: 
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4 
Cordova Platforms : android 6.2.3 
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.5.0 

System: 
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5 
Node : v8.1.3 
npm : 5.0.3 
OS : Windows 10
```

**EDITED :** 
So I change folder name from **26.0.0-preview** to **26.0.0-rc1** and I got a new error :

```
Errors during XML parse:
White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required between publicId and
systemId.
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
  - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required between publicId and
systemId.]
Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
    > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0,26.1.0).
      Required by:
          project : > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.1
       > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0,26.1.0).
          > Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v4.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from
https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml.
                > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required
between publicId and systemId.
    > Could not resolve com.android.support:customtabs:[26.0.0,26.1.0).
      Required by:
          project : > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.1
       > Could not resolve com.android.support:customtabs:[26.0.0,26.1.0).
          > Failed to list versions for com.android.support:customtabs.
             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from
https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/customtabs/maven-metadata.xml.
                > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required
between publicId and systemId.
```

Comment: `Observed package id 'build-tools;26.0.0-rc1' in inconsistent location 'E:\SDK\build-tools\26.0.0-preview' (Expected 'E:\SDK\build-tools\26.0.0-rc1')` do you have 26.0.0-rc1 build tools installed in android sdk?

Comment: @suraj I have `26.0.0-preview` , how can I get `26.0.0-rc1` ?

Comment: can you add output of `ionic info`?

Comment: @suraj ,Also you can see full error and info on [this issue](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/237)

Comment: from your other linked question, you are targeting android sdk version 25. From the error message, onesignal depends on support library from version 26.. You should probably look for a lower version plugin, if you plan to target sdk 25..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution! At the first is better to see [onesignal-plugin-versions](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/releases) ;

according to that :

> **2.2.0 Release :**
>
> Dropped Android 2.3 (API 9) support, minimum is now 4.0.3 (API 15).

So we have two choices :

1. Increase `minSdkVersion` in `config.xml`
2. Decrease `onesignal-cordova-plugin` version (`ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin@2.1.2`)